# Using GAPI how do I get visitor count on each page?

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Like the old days, I like to have visitor counting or page hits *on each page* on my website, which will be different on each page. Using GAPI I can get total visitor but it will be the same figure on each page, but I can't find the parameter to count on each page.

Here's my code so far:

```
    define('ga_email','mymail@example.com');
    define('ga_password','password');
    define('ga_profile_id','xxxxxxxx');
    require 'gapi.class.php';
    $ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);
    $ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('browser','browserVersion'),array('pageviews','visits'));
    echo $ga->getVisits();
```

Comment: Use the [`ga:pagePath`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath) dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the visitor count for each page, you have to break down the desired metrics using the [`ga:pagePath`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath) dimension. This dimension contains the path and query parameters of a pageview. If you track multiple domains, add the [`ga:hostname`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_hostname) dimension.